# C++ call derived function from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class and I want for it to call a derived class method if it's called from a base class. Is this possible?
for example

```
class A{
 public:
 C();
 D();
};

class B:public A{
 public:
  C();
}

void A::D(){
 C();
}

main(){
 B b;
 b.D();
}
```

So that `b.D()` calls function `A::D()` which in turn calls `B::C()`. Is this default behaviour or is there a way to make it happen?

Comment: `virtual` functions perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the keyword *virtual*.
However the *override* (C++11) is optional and helps to find errors during compilation but I recommend to use it.

```
class A {
 public:
   virtual void C();
   void D();
};

class B : public A {
 public:
   void C() override;
}

void A::D() {
  C();
}

int main() {
 B b;
 b.D();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that C is a virtual function:

```
class A{
 public:
 virtual void C();
 void D();
};
```